# How do I declare OutputDebugStringA without windows.h macros?

Tags: c++, winapi

You know how Python has `from urllib import *`, but also offers `from urllib import request`, so you can just import that one symbol? Unfortunately C/C++ don't offer that but that's what I would like to do here: `from windows.h import OutputDebugStringA`, because all I need is that one function. This is for a personal project only.

I used `cl.exe main.cpp /EP` to preprocess and it tells me that this should work

```
typedef char CHAR;
typedef  const CHAR *LPCSTR, *PCSTR;
__declspec(dllimport)
void
__stdcall
OutputDebugStringA(
     LPCSTR lpOutputString
    );
```

But I'm still getting a linker error:
`main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl OutputDebugStringA(char const *)" (__imp_?OutputDebugStringA@@YAXPEBD@Z) referenced in ...`

Why?

Comment: "*I don't like to include windows.h unless I have to*" - why? You *SHOULD* be using `windows.h` for Windows development.

Comment: Your code says `__stdcall` but your linker error says `__cdecl`.  Do you have a macro in your project that redefines `__stdcall`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think I have such a macro, the compiler seems to do that on its own.

Comment: A compiler will not automatically compile code using `__stdcall` as using `__cdecl` instead.  They are very distinct calling conventions with different runtime sematics. Calling convention mismatches will cause problems when the code is run. If this is your *real* copy/pasted error message, not something you (mis)typed by hand, then something else is going on.  Fix the mismatch first, and then if you are still getting the linker error, make sure you are linking to `kernel32.lib`.

Comment: Just include windows.h - simple - works - why make life complicated - Why have problems in the future

Comment: If windows.h slows down your compilation a lot, consider defining WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before including.
But really, you should be including that header in every source file where you do windows development. That's just the correct thing to do

Comment: Please, could we focus on the technical issue? If you think it's wrong not to include it, please consider ignoring this question. Thank you.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg You still have a problem, regardless of `__stdcall` or `__cdecl` -- where is the `OutputDebugStringA` function located?   The linker will still give you an error due to you not specifying the import library that contains `OutptDebugStringA` (is it `kernel32.lib`, don't remember now).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: `OutputDebugStringA()` is an exported function in `kernel32.dll`.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg - You are just going to create a headache in the future.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, just when you got to me, I was writing the comment.  Thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I do link against `kernel32.lib`, so that should fix the linker issue. I don't think `__stdcall` is getting redefined by a macro because if it would that would be reflected in the output of `/EP` (runs preprocessor). The output of the preprocessor says `__stdcall`, but the linker error still says `__cdecl`.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg If that is C++ code you're compiling, then you are mangling the function name when you compiled that module.  It isn't the same `OutputDebugStringA` as the one defined in kernel32.lib.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Derp. Yes that was the problem, thank you! `extern "C"` fixed it.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg [Don't you love the downvotes :)](http://img.myconfinedspace.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Technically-Correct-Man.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the Windows API is `C` based, and thus the functions that are to be called are `C` functions, not C++ functions.

The problem when compiled under a C++ compiler is that the function name gets mangled (due to C++ use of function overloading).  Thus the function name winds up being different than the actual function name that is defined in the import library (in this case `kernel32.lib`).  You therefore get the linker error that the function cannot be found.

The fix is to use `extern "C"` as a qualifier to the function, so that C++ does not mangle the function name.

However, I do **not** recommend this for Windows development, i.e. not including the `windows.h` header file.  Problems such as this can be avoided by including the `windows.h` header file.

Comment: I would also not recommend not including `windows.h` in general. Thank you for your help despite disapproving. :)

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg - Two double negatives - perhaps improve that statement to make it more readable

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg If you have a better reason than "I don't like to include windows.h unless I have to." you should probably include it in your question. Otherwise your post suggests that you to do think it's a good idea to generally try to avoid including it.

Comment: @RossRidge I tried to add an explanation to the question.

Answer (score 2):

So the following does the trick:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall OutputDebugStringA(const char* lpOutputString);
```